# Subtrair data para obter contagem regressiva

Tags: javascript, jquery

Atualmente possuo o seguinte código:

```
var now = new Date();
var countTo = 50 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 + now.valueOf();
$('.timer').countdown(countTo, function(event) {
    var $this = $(this);
    switch(event.type) {
        case "seconds":
        case "minutes":
        case "hours":
        case "days":
        case "weeks":
        case "daysLeft":
            $this.find('span.'+event.type).html(event.value);
            break;
        case "finished":
            $this.hide();
            break;
    }
});
```

Toda a vez que recarrego a página a contagem começa de novo. Eu precisaria setar uma data especifica (14:30:00 08/01/2015) para comparação e contagem regressiva para aquele dia.

A contagem atualmente começa a partir de 50 dias.

Comment: Qual é o plugin que está a usar? pode fazer um jsFiddle com um exemplo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seu código está a usar a data atual (+50 dias) para a contagem decrescente. Se mudar o valor dessa variável para um numero fixo (data fixa) então vai ter o comportamento que quer.

Por exemplo:

```
var countTo = new Date('14:30:00 08/01/2015');
```

Não sei exatamente qual o plugin que usa, mas supondo que é o **[.countdown()](http://plugins.jquery.com/kbw.countdown/)** do jQuery pode ver um exemplo aqui:

http://jsfiddle.net/Tc5tn/

***Nota:*** conforme o [@abfurlan](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21646/subtrair-data-para-obter-contagem-regressiva/21660?noredirect=1#comment39159_21660) referiu nos comentários em baixo, seria melhor usar o formato `"8 January 2015 14:30:00:00"` pois a minha primeira sugestão pode ser mal lida se o Locale do computador fôr diferente.

Comment: O formato da data não seria "8 January 2015 14:30:00:00"? http://jsfiddle.net/Tc5tn/1/, no seu exemplo esta dando 410 dias, acho q esta errado

Comment: @abfurlan no meu caso dá 204 dias, mas é uma boa observação e o seu formato é melhor que o meu. Aqui no lado europeu o meu formato funciona "por acaso"

Comment: Interessante, talvez seja interessante descrever na resposta

Comment: Obrigado. Consolidei a resposta a sua resposta Sergio com a consideração feita pelo @abfurlan e funcionou.